# how to flatten an inherited class?

Tags: java, oop, object, inheritance

Is there a way to flatten inherited classes to discover which functions belong to what class?

if you have a class like:

```
public class Person
{
    public String name;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

and an inherited class like

```
public class Worker extends Person
{
    public String job;

    public void setJob(String job){
        this.job = job;
    }

    public String getJob(){
        return this.job;
    }
}
```

When you instantiate Worker, is there a way to find out that Set/GetName belongs to the Person class?

I've seen suggestions of using an interface to find this information out but i'm not sure how an interface would be best used to show the kind of function relationships here.  Are there any cheats to being able to reference particular classes within an inherited class?

**EDIT:**

To answer why I wish to do this:  I basically want to be able to loop over the methods in an object and ignore ones that come from a certain class, in this instance I want to ignore the Person class.

My real world example isn't quite as simple as this, but i couldn't think of a better way of working out which methods belong to what class without "flattening" them.

Comment: Can you explain why you need it?

Comment: @  Jarede: You could check java reflection. You could inspect declaredMethods for example : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class...)

Comment: Jayan comment is right. If you are using Eclipse, the object inspector (that shows the methods available for an object after you write the `.` dot), shows in bold type the methods declared in the more specific class (so, for a `Worker` variable, `setJob` would be in bold and `setName` would not)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `isBridge` method in `Method` class can be used to check whether the method is declared in the `Person` or `Worker` class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Worker worker = new Worker();
    Class clazz = worker.getClass();
    Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();

    for(Method method :methods)
    {
        System.out.println(method.getName()+ " is in Worker: "+ !method.isBridge());
    }
}
```

The above code will produce the output as:

```
setName is in Worker: false
getName is in Worker: false
setJob is in Worker: true
getJob is in Worker: true
```

Comment: @Jarede, Oops. Its a typo. Fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) to check whether a method exists within an object, but I don't see why would you do this. Remembering how polymorphism works, we should treat your instance of `Worker` either as `Worker` or as `Person`, but why would you treat it as a `Worker` as "not quite a `Person`"?

```
Worker w = new Worker();
Class c = w.getClass();
Class noparams[] = {};

boolean hasSetJob = false;
try{
    c.getDeclaredMethod("setJob", noparams);
    hasSetJob = true;
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    hasSetJob = false;
}
```

Anyway any uses of *Reflection API* in applicative (and not framework) code considered as a hack and a sign that you want to do weird things (which are usually wrong).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, you could try this way:

```
Class c = new Worker().getClass();
Method[] ma = c.getMethods();

for (Method m : ma) {
    String methodClass = m.getDeclaringClass().getName();
    if(methodClass.equals("net.yourpackage.Person")){
        // do something...
    }
    else if(methodClass.equals("net.yourpackage.Worker")){
        // do something...
    }
    // ... other classes
    else if(methodClass.equals("java.lang.Object")){
        // do something else...
    }
}
```